# Application hosted in IIS7 does not provide credentials to Web Service on another server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, active-directory, web

At the moment we identified that the error is due to security issues.

The old server ServerA managed to communicate with WebServerC without problems, now the new server ServerB can connect but the provided credentials are not enough for it to access WebServerC which has the Web Service.

ServerA –> WebServerC (Connection OK and Security OK)
ServerB –> WebServerC (Connection OK and Security Failed) Instead of showing the Web Service it shows the asp.net "Login" screen.

This is all under a Corporate Active Directory with Windows Server 2008. What could be the problem? ServerA has nothing special and ServerB is new but the App running is the same.

Comment: What exact error-message were you getting on ServerB? Were you getting any error-messages on ServerC?

Answer (score 0):

Probably for ServerB the flag Trusted For Delegation is not set.
In this case a user can be authenticated on the ServerB, but ServerB can't use this credential to authenticate on the WebServerC.